# Close tab from address bar?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-tabs

I know there are special commands in Firefox that can be accessed through address bar, such as **about:config** or **about:blank**

I was wondering if it's possible to close a tab or a window using similar command entered into an address bar. I'm not looking for a hotkey.

Thanks.

Comment: Flagged comment for rude language, there is simply no need for that. That said, The most likely reason for the downvote is that the question is very 'google-able' and you've not shown any effort to do so. Also, an indication of why you want to do this may be helpful to others find context for you. Lastly,  Firefox tab headers contain a X for closing the tab, on the right hand side, why not use that rather than a command?

Comment: This should have added why the command from address bar was needed to consider from given context (as Steven had suggested), and not reuse the exact unimproved question to [cross-post at other SE site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43985115). Hence, -1.

Answer (score 1):

No, although there exist addons such as Vimperator which add commands for this.

In some other browsers, you can call `javascript:window.close()` *(which is 24 keystrokes more than `Ctrl+W`)*, but Firefox forbids this and prints an error to the developer console.

Comment: **javascript:window.close()** might be a thing I'm looking for. Is there any way I can get it to work in Firefox?